1990s or early 2000s TV series about a boy trying to go home, he ends up on different adventures accompanied by 2 companion
I used to watch a TV show in my youth, I'm pretty sure the show was 90s or early 2000s, which I can't remember anything about it, neither its name.
I remember the main character was teenage boy trying to return home to earth. There was a female character which was a warrior/ assassin who had two blades, and horns or marking on her head and kept threatening to kill the teen boy but ended up joining his travels. The one scene I remember was the warrior girl sat down to meditate, her blades under her chin and she started to chant "aye ya ya ya, aye ya ya ya".

Was this live-action or animated?

Trying to return home to Earth? Are they traveling in space? Jumping through portals? Trying to get a specific Spell to transport him back to earth? (i.e. Sci-Fi or Fantasy type show?)

I can't recall much but I believe there was a ship involved and the main protagonist was trying find his sister and return home to earth. This was a live-action  Sci-Fi series. I can only recall the female character because she was a warrior with two blades, and had two markings or horns on her temple. She didn't like the main character but in time grew to like him. I remember a scene where they had an argument where she then sat done to meditate, put both her blades under her chin and began a chant.. and that's all I can recall.

Your question was closed as a Duplicate. That's not because it's a bad question. We just have a policy that story-id questions get closed if they share an answer.

Might it be Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!?

In the 25th century, humans discover an alien device dubbed the "Nullifier". This device is said to be capable of controlling, or worse, destroying the universe. Irwin 1138 (Barrie Ingham), the second-greatest mind of his time splits the Nullifier into six pieces, which are subsequently dispersed through time. Dr. Zoetrope (Derek Webster), Irwin's rival and the greatest mind of his time, seeks to retrieve and reassemble the device with the help of his time traveling power armor, with Irwin following in his "time pod" to beat his rival to the pieces.
The chase leads them both to 1995, where they encounter 14-year-old Josh Kirby. After a brief conflict, Zoetrope flees into the time stream with a piece of the Nullifier that landed in Kirby's garden, and Irwin gives chase, only to bring Josh along for the ride by accident. Irwin explains the Nullifier is an indestructible weapon he scattered across time to prevent Zoetrope using it to wipe out the universe. Unable to return to his home era, Josh accompanies Irwin, his alien companion Prism and later, half-human warrior Azabeth Siege (Jennifer Burns), in the race to collect the Nullifier pieces.

Azabeth does wield two blades (shaped kind of like bolts of lightning). I don't remember any forehead markings, but looking through the trailer, she does have some oddly shaped eyebrows and some rings in her hair in one of the episodes:
 Click to enlarge
According to this review, she has a moment of chanting.

I laughed more during Josh Kirby: Chapter 3 than I have for most of the movies I've seen this year combined. In this chapter, Josh randomly and inexplicably flies out of the spaceship and lands on a Toy (here, toys apparently include Mexicans) planet where he is assaulted by an extremely horny ragdoll and a semi-retarded bear.
Back again is the unspeakably random creature "Prism", who takes a turn for the darker side as he cavorts around the spaceship, and the hilariously bizarre mannerisms of Azabeth--who performs an elaborate chanting ritual, which when combined with Prism's epilepsy in the corner of the screen, makes the laughs flow with ease.

Clip with Azabeth chanting as you remember
https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxZhW69YNAa4deu7P99ppM5ojdgbLZv71L?si=5IlfyGKsFLejXkE-
Trailer




Yes! This is the show, I just saw the video and I recognise all the characters now! Josh Kirby -Time warrior was one of my favourites growing up, but I just couldn't remember anything about the show other than the warrior chanting and her two blades. Thank you so much for finding this. Now I can relive my childhood and share it with my family.
